# Fwrite in foreachloop PHP

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite

I want to write the contents of an array to new file.

So far as it stands my file is only containing the last element of my array and not the first two.  So the text in the file output2.txt is Edward only.

Have I misunderstood something here?

```
$array = array ("Sarah", "William", "Edward");

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $myfile = fopen("output2.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile,$value);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: More efficency to implode the array than loop it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array ("Sarah", "William", "Edward");
$txt = "";
foreach ($array as $value) {
        $txt = $txt . $value;;
} 

$myfile = fopen("output2.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$txt);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Don't include file manipulation functions in loop, Create a string then write it to file.

And like @Dagon suggested you can simply Implode a array using Implode function.

```
<?php
$array = array ("Sarah", "William", "Edward");
$txt = implode(",", $array);

$myfile = fopen("output2.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for improvement :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$myfile = fopen("output2.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$abcd = "";
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $abcd .= $value;       
} 

fwrite($myfile,$abcd);
fclose($myfile);
```

you are creating new file each time try this may help you